What is the right way to close a pair of QThread/Process?
In my main pyqt5 program i instantiate some classes.
Each of this classes are born a QThread and a Process.
I am having trouble closing all this pairs of QThreads/Processes.
Here is what i do:
main close event:
    def closeEvent(self,event):
        try:
            if self.closeEvent_isSet == False:
                self.closeEvent_isSet = True

                # unsure that record deck is not recording
                if self.record_deck_instance.deck_status != "stopped":
                    self.record_deck_instance.stop_and_close()
                    event.ignore()
                    return None

                # unsure that ip call is not recording
                for i in range(0, 3):
                    if self.ip_calls_record_deck_instance.ip_calls[i]["deck_status"] == "recording":
                        self.ip_calls_record_deck_instance.stop_and_close()
                        event.ignore()
                        return None

                event.ignore()
                self.final_slice_instance.put_to_plot = False
                self.final_slice_instance.put_to_pyaudio = False
                self.final_slice_instance.put_to_record = False
                self.deck_1_instance.put_to_q = False
                self.deck_2_instance.put_to_q = False
                self.music_clip_deck_instance.put_to_q = False

                # stop information frame
                self.information_frame_instance.close()

                # stop deck 1
                self.deck_1_instance.close()

                # stop deck 2
                self.deck_2_instance.close()

                # stop speackers deck
                self.speackers_deck_instance.close()

                # stop music clip deck
                self.music_clip_deck_instance.close()

                # stop final slice
                self.final_slice_instance.close()

                # stop final slice plot
                self.final_slice_plot_instance.close()

                # stop final slice pyaudio
                self.final_slice_pyaudio_instance.close()

                # stop record deck
                self.record_deck_instance.close()

                # stop ip call 1
                if self.ui.ip_call_1_frame.isVisible():
                    self.ui.ip_call_1_dismiss.click()
                self.ip_call_1_instance.close()

                # stop ip call 2
                if self.ui.ip_call_2_frame.isVisible():
                    self.ui.ip_call_2_dismiss.click()
                self.ip_call_2_instance.close()

                # stop ip call 3
                if self.ui.ip_call_3_frame.isVisible():
                    self.ui.ip_call_3_dismiss.click()
                self.ip_call_3_instance.close()

                # stop ip calls (aiortc)
                self.ip_calls_instance.close()

                # stop speackers deck secondary
                self.speackers_deck_secondary_instance.close()

                # stop secondary slice
                self.secondary_slice_instance.close()

                # stop secondary slice pyaudio
                self.secondary_slice_pyaudio_instance.close()

                # ip calls record deck
                self.ip_calls_record_deck_instance.close()

                # player list
                self.player_list_instance.close()

                self.close_timer = QtCore.QTimer()
                self.close_timer.timeout.connect(lambda: self.MainWindow.close())
                self.close_timer.setSingleShot(True)
                self.close_timer.start(20)
                return None
            else:
                if all(not item for item in self.processes.values()):
                    # stop sync processes thread
                    self.sync_processes_instance.close()

                    event.accept()
                    if self.restart:
                        QtCore.QProcess.startDetached(sys.executable, sys.argv)
                else:
                    try:
                        self.close_timer.disconnect()
                    except:
                        pass
                    self.close_timer = QtCore.QTimer()
                    self.close_timer.timeout.connect(lambda: self.MainWindow.close())
                    self.close_timer.setSingleShot(True)
                    self.close_timer.start(20)

                    event.ignore()
                    return None
        except:
            print(traceback.format_exc())

close method of one class instance:
    def close(self):
        try:
            print("close")
            if self.is_closing == False:
                self.is_closing = True
                self.queue.put({"type":"close"})
                print("queue put close...")
            else:
                try:
                    self.child_process.terminate()
                    self.emitter.quit()
                except:
                    pass

                while(self.queue.qsize()!=0):
                    _ = self.queue.get()

                manage_processes_class.deinit_process(self)
                self.main_self.processes["information_frame_instance_process_state"] = False
        except:
            self.main_self.processes["information_frame_instance_process_state"] = False
            error_message = traceback.format_exc()
            #self.main_self.open_information_frame_error_window(error_message)

After the first run of this close() method, one close item is putted in process queue. Process send close message via emitter to QThread and then process is return None. Then QThread emits close signal to parent class instance and return None. Finally the parent class instance is calling close_now() from the emitted signal.
close_now method:
    def close_now(self):
        try:
            print("close_now")
            self.is_closing = True
            self.close()
        except:
            self.is_closing = True
            self.close()

This workaround finally works, but what about if an error oqueured in QThread. Then the close signal will never emitted so the close_now will never be called, so no stop of QThread/Process.
I want to modern solution using: terminate(), join() and quit() and to be as simple as possible.
Edit: I change the main closeEvent:
    def closeEvent(self,event):
        try:
            self.MainWindow.hide()
            # unsure that record deck is not recording
            if self.record_deck_instance.deck_status != "stopped":
                self.record_deck_instance.stop_and_close()
                event.ignore()
                return None

            # unsure that ip call is not recording
            for i in range(0, 3):
                if self.ip_calls_record_deck_instance.ip_calls[i]["deck_status"] == "recording":
                    self.ip_calls_record_deck_instance.stop_and_close()
                    event.ignore()
                    return None

            self.final_slice_instance.put_to_plot = False
            self.final_slice_instance.put_to_pyaudio = False
            self.final_slice_instance.put_to_record = False
            self.deck_1_instance.put_to_q = False
            self.deck_2_instance.put_to_q = False
            self.music_clip_deck_instance.put_to_q = False

            # stop information frame
            self.information_frame_instance.close()

            # stop deck 1
            self.deck_1_instance.close()

            # stop deck 2
            self.deck_2_instance.close()

            # stop speackers deck
            self.speackers_deck_instance.close()

            # stop music clip deck
            self.music_clip_deck_instance.close()

            # stop final slice
            self.final_slice_instance.close()

            # stop final slice plot
            self.final_slice_plot_instance.close()

            # stop final slice pyaudio
            self.final_slice_pyaudio_instance.close()

            # stop record deck
            self.record_deck_instance.close()

            # stop ip call 1
            if self.ui.ip_call_1_frame.isVisible():
                self.ui.ip_call_1_dismiss.click()
            self.ip_call_1_instance.close()

            # stop ip call 2
            if self.ui.ip_call_2_frame.isVisible():
                self.ui.ip_call_2_dismiss.click()
            self.ip_call_2_instance.close()

            # stop ip call 3
            if self.ui.ip_call_3_frame.isVisible():
                self.ui.ip_call_3_dismiss.click()
            self.ip_call_3_instance.close()

            # stop ip calls (aiortc)
            self.ip_calls_instance.close()

            # stop speackers deck secondary
            self.speackers_deck_secondary_instance.close()

            # stop secondary slice
            self.secondary_slice_instance.close()

            # stop secondary slice pyaudio
            self.secondary_slice_pyaudio_instance.close()

            # ip calls record deck
            self.ip_calls_record_deck_instance.close()

            # player list
            self.player_list_instance.close()

            # stop sync processes thread
            self.sync_processes_instance.close()

            event.accept()
            if self.restart:
                QtCore.QProcess.startDetached(sys.executable, sys.argv)
        except:
            print(traceback.format_exc())

Now one close method is:
    def close(self):
        try:
            self.queue.put({"type":"close"})
            try:
                self.child_process.join()
                self.child_process.terminate()
                self.emitter.quit()
            except:
                pass

            while(self.queue.qsize()!=0):
                _ = self.queue.get()

            manage_processes_class.deinit_process(self)
        except:
            error_message = traceback.format_exc()
            self.main_self.open_information_frame_error_window(error_message)

But it takes 12 seconds to accept the event... :/

you should not use try/except like this. a try should have inside only those commands that you might throw an exception and then you should use except to capture that specific exception (don't use bare excepts). What you are doing is basically putting all your code inside a try. Don't do that.

Also if something throws and exception, don;t call it again inside the except. In the function close_now the only thing that could throw an exception is the call to self.close(). So if this actually throws an exception and you call it again inside except, it's most likely going to throw and exception again, only that this time you are not capturing that exception. Instead inside the except you should do things that happen when calling close fails.

@Cincinnatus A lot of code are now gone. But it takes 12 seconds to accept the event
